# C#/WPF: Align top border of a data grid to the top border of an image varying in size

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am developing a WPF application using C#. A grid divides the application into 2 columns. In the left column I placed a DataGrid and in the right column I have an Image. The image has the option `Stretch="Uniform"` set and therefore adopts its height to optimally fill the grid column keeping its aspect ratio, if the size of the main window is changed. The image has to be vertically centered within the column.

As a result the above setup leads to a white/blank border on top of the image. I would like to align the top of the dataGrid in the left column to the top of the automatically scaled image in the right column. Therefore I have to somehow bind the data of the image distance from the top border to the data grid distance from the top border.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to set VerticalAlignment="Top" on the elements in the grid panel. Example below:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           MaxWidth="100"
           Source="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"></Image>

        <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" 
              Margin="10 0 0 0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column2"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column3"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column4"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ok, but I want the image vertically centered. I will add this to my question. Therefore I have somehow to bind the data of the image distance from the top border to the data grid distance from the top border.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question. You may need to clarify it further. What stops you from setting the alignment of the grid that contains both image and data grid to center? Then you can vertical align the image and data grid to top. Remember you can always put the grid containing your content in another grid. See the updated code.